# Angle and velocity of a bouncing ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, velocity, projectile, drag

[image]

I'm modelling a projectile motion (soccer ball in my case) shot with an angle and an initial velocity,
when the ball hit the ground how can I determine its new launch angle an velocity?
Note : air drag and ground friction are included

Answer (score 0):

If it lands at an angle $\theta$ to the ground, at speed $V$, it's horizontal and vertical components are $V\cos\theta$ and $V\sin\theta$ respectively.

Leave the horizontal component unchanged ($V_H$)and change the vertical component to $V_V = eV\sin\theta$ (upwards)

where $e$ is the coefficient of restitution, choose a number between $0$ and $1$.

It's new speed is $\sqrt{V_H^2 +V_V^2}$ and the angle is $\tan^{-1}(\frac{V_V}{V_H})$.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution

Comment: but how can I determine (e) and I don't have the velocity after collision ? or just give it an arbitrary value like 0.7

Comment: Since the ball has finite size, when it hits the ground the friction imparts some angular momentum on it because of the instantaneous torque. So the ball will also be spinning when it bounces off the ground. The horizontal velocity $V_H$ will be the velocity of the center of mass.

Comment: Yes, you can choose it and if you have a graphic for this model, you'll see what happens.  Choosing e=0.9, lis ike a kids bouncy ball maybe 0.7 is realistic for a football and 0.3 gives a low bounce, perhaps realistic for soft or wet ground in a football match...and yes it would be spinning, but as you add more detail like that it'll get complicated

Comment: @JohnHunter thank you so much

Comment: If you model it finely enough to account for air resistance, then you *definitely* also have to account for rotational motion of the ball, and importantly the difference between the surface rotational rate and the ground movement rate. A spinning ball will impart linear acceleration if it hits the ground at any rotational rate than the exact match of its groundspeed. And to some extent it will get this horizontal acceleration from its vertical movement component!(due to ball deformation making the action point be *not* underneath the mass point , nor at the initial contact point!

Comment: And if you want to be accurate, consider the aerodynamics of a spinning ball. The Magnus effect is not something to sneeze at, it can drastically affect a ball's trajectory! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OSrvzNW9FE

Comment: @PcMan I will check it out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to include air drag, you will need to know how it relates to the velocity, and then you pretty much need to do a numeric simulation to find the path and final speed.  Also, as PcMan points out, the friction impulse which imparts a spin to the ball will also change the horizontal velocity. Instead of assuming a coefficient of restitution (which is poorly defined for a bounce at an angle) I would assume a fractional loss of energy (or none).